# Preprocessing invalid xml before feeding it to a parser

Tags: c++, beginner, parsing

As part of a larger project I'm writing to learn C++, I'm trying to read through some almost-XML files generated by another program. Unfortunately this program uses its own custom escaping logic, so some of these files aren't actually valid XML. As far as I can tell, its escape logic works like this:

- Attribute values are always surrounded with double quotes. The only escape sequence is `\"`, evaluating to a double quote. Backslashes elsewhere are just interpreted literally; it's impossible for a value to end with a backslash.
- Nested elements always have the opening outer tag on one line, each inner tag on its own line, and the closing outer tag on another.
- Tags with text content are always entirely on a single line, and interpret all characters between the opening tag and closing tag literally. It is impossible for a copy of the closing tag to be in the text content, but other tags may be.

In practice the files have a bit more structure than this, but I've been trying to work off of just these assumptions to keep the code flexible.

As an example, this is a possible, invalid XML, input:

```xml
<outer attr="&amp;value\"">
    <empty />
    <inner><notnested></outer></inner>
</outer>
```

Which is equivalent to this valid XML:

```xml
<outer attr="&amp;amp;value&quot;">
    <empty />
    <inner>&lt;notnested&gt;&lt;/outer&gt;</inner>
</outer>
```

My approach to dealing with this is to do some simplified parsing over these files to convert them into valid XML, before feeding them into a more traditional XML parser (leaning towards [pugixml](https://pugixml.org/), but open to change if it makes things easier). Here are the relevant functions in a small demo program:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

static void put_xml_escaped(char c, std::stringstream& stream) {
    switch (c) {
        case '"': stream << "&quot;"; break;
        case '\'': stream << "&apos;"; break;
        case '<': stream << "&lt;"; break;
        case '>': stream << "&gt;"; break;
        case '&': stream << "&amp;"; break;
        default: stream << c; break;
    }
}

static std::stringstream preprocess_file(std::string filename) {
    enum tag_parse_state {
                     // "    <tag attr="val">content</tag>    "
        before_tag,  //  ^^^^
        tag_name,    //      ^^^^
        tag_body,    //          ^^^^^^^    ^
        attr,        //                 ^^^^
        content,     //                      ^^^^^^^
        closing_tag, //                             ^^^^^^
        closed       //                                   ^^^^
    };

    std::ifstream file{filename};
    std::stringstream processed{};

    for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); ) {
        tag_parse_state state = before_tag;

        size_t tag_name_start;
        size_t closing_tag_start, closing_tag_end;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
            auto c = line[i];

            if (state == before_tag) {
                if (c == '<') {
                    processed << c;
                    state = tag_name;
                    tag_name_start = i + 1;
                } else if (!isspace(c)) {
                    throw std::runtime_error(
                        "Failed to parse line (text before inital tag): " + line
                    );
                }

            } else if (state == tag_name) {
                processed << c;
                if (c == ' ' || c == '>') {
                    // Nice little coincidence: if we're parsing over a closing tag, this will
                    //  double up on the '/' and thus not find itself
                    auto closing_tag_str = (
                        "</" + line.substr(tag_name_start, i - tag_name_start) + ">"
                    );
                    closing_tag_start = line.rfind(closing_tag_str);
                    closing_tag_end = (
                        closing_tag_start == std::string::npos
                        ? std::string::npos
                        : closing_tag_start + closing_tag_str.size() - 1
                    );

                    if (c == ' ') {
                        state = tag_body;
                    } else {
                        state = closing_tag_start == std::string::npos ? closed : content;
                    }
                }

            } else if (state == tag_body) {
                processed << c;
                if (c == '"') {
                    state = attr;
                } else if (c == '>') {
                    state = closing_tag_start == std::string::npos ? closed : content;
                }

            } else if (state == attr) {
                if (c == '"') {
                    processed << c;
                    state = tag_body;
                } else if (c == '\\' && i + 1 < line.size() && line[i + 1] == '"') {
                    put_xml_escaped('"', processed);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    put_xml_escaped(c, processed);
                }

            } else if (state == content) {
                put_xml_escaped(c, processed);
                if (i + 1 >= closing_tag_start) {
                    state = closing_tag;
                }

            } else if (state == closing_tag) {
                processed << c;
                if (i >= closing_tag_end) {
                    state = closed;
                }

            } else if (state == closed) {
                if (!isspace(c)) {
                    throw std::runtime_error(
                        "Failed to parse line (text after closing tag): " + line
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        if (state != closed) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to parse line (missed closing tag): " + line);
        }
    }

    return processed;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << preprocess_file("example.xml").str() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm interested in feedback on:

- General best practices (minus code style)
- Edge cases I may have missed
- Algorithmic improvements - I don't think you can do much better than O(n) when using a state machine like this, but maybe there's a completely different approach.

Comment: This isn't really an XML question. It's about a proprietary data syntax that has some resemblances to XML, but you can't use any XML tooling, so this doesn't help you.

Comment: Fair enough, removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `enum class`

Consider using [`enum class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) instead of a plain `enum` for a little more type safety.

I would also recommend you use all-caps for the names of the `enum` options, as this is commonly done and is a strong hint that those are constants and not variables.

## Prefer using `switch`-statements when `enum`s are involved

Use a `switch`-statement instead of a chain of `if`-`else`-statements when checking the value of an `enum` variable. Most compilers will then be able to emit warnings if you forget a `case` statement. It also makes the code a little bit more readable.

## Make `preprocess_file()` take `istream` and `ostream`s as parameters

Your `preprocess_file()` has a filename as an argument, and returns a `std::stringstream`. However, that means that now it is responsible for opening the file, and returning the result as a `std::stringstream` is inefficient if you are just going to write it to `std::out` afterwards. Consider having this function take two parameters: one for the input stream, and one for the output stream, like so:

```
void preprocess(std::istream &file, std::ostream &processed) {
    ...
}
```

Then in `main()` you can write:

```
preprocess(std::ifstream("example.xml"), std::cout);
std::cout << "\n";
```

If you want to be able to write `std::cout << preprocess(...)`, that is possible too, but then you have to make it a `class` and add a [`friend operator<<(std::ostream &, preprocess &)` function](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-the-io-operators/), which might be a bit overkill for your application.

## Missing error checking

I/O errors can happen at any time, both when reading from and writing to a file. You could add checks after every I/O operation, but that would quickly lead to a lot of messy code. Luckily, any error state persists, so what you can do is just add [checks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) at the end of `preprocess_file()`, like so:

```
if (file.fail()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error while reading input");
}

if (processed.fail()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error while writing output");
}
```

## Performance

You are going over each character individually, most of the time just copying it to the output. For each state you only have a few characters you want to match. Consider using [`std::string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to get the position of the first interesting character; the standard library might do that in a more optimal way.

Comment: Lot of good tips, thanks. I realized I didn't mention it in the post, but for what it's worth I was looking at feeding [pugixml from a stream](https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#loading.stream), hence why I left it outputting the stringstream. I can definitely see how having the parent function manage ownership would be better though.